# Assigning to copy of a map seems to be modifying the original

Tags: dictionary, go, pointers, reference

I have a variable `decodedToken` (type: struct), and I access one of its values called "Claims" through a type assertion:

```
claims := decodedToken.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)
```

I then loop through the `claims` (type: map[string]interface{}), and modify its values in place:

```
  for key := range claims {
        claims[key] = "modified"+key 
    }
```

Hence, I expect that the original `decodedToken` variable would be unchanged, since I have just performed an operation on the `claims` variable. However, `decodedToken` is also changed to my modified value.

My question is why is this so, and how do I leave the `decodedToken` untouched?

Comment: "I expect that the original decodedToken variable would be unchanged" Your expectation is not backed by how maps work in Go. Please take the Tour of Go and consult the language spec. Maps and slices have reference semantics in Go.

Comment: "how do I leave the decodedToken untouched?" Do not modify claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since claims is a `reference type`, like a map or slice.

The solution is make a `deep copy` of any referenced data. Unfortunately there are no universal way to make a deep copy of any map in Go. So you should make your own.

Or more practical way to do your job is making a new object(variable) to contain the modified `decodedToken`.

Also, it's not good to iterated a map and modify its value in a same statement.

Comment: There are no reference types in Go. A slice is not what "reference type" typically means in CS.